# input_shape keras NN

Tags: neural-networks, keras

I'm working on a problem where I need to predict one value out of many features, and I have multiple measurements for each feature.

Below is a simplified version of my problem. [image]

So, what I do is just taking mean value of all the measurements for each person and fitting the keras NN model. I've seen in keras documentation `input_shape` parameter. Probably I can somehow specify it.

My thought was I loose too much information just taking the mean.

**Question1:** How can I say to my model: "look, each id has 3 features for which there is 3 measurements"? Can I do it through `input_shape`?

**Question2(bonus):** what is `noise_shape` in `dropout` layer?

PS: number of measurements is equal for each id.